# Is there a way to create hard link between /DCIM in internal storage and external (removable SD card)

Tags: android, terminal, android-external-storage, rooted-device

I am using rooted crDroid 9.5 custom rom and Gcam, I can't find an option in the system or camera settings to automatically save pictures and videos to the removable micro SD.
I was thinking of a way to create a hard link between the DCIM folders using the terminal.
If there is no way to do it automatically I was thinking of a script that moves all files to the removable micro SD card folder.

I entered:
`ln sdcard/DCIM/Camera external_sd/DCIM/Camera`
it returned an error stating that it cannot create hard link because it's a cross-device link.

Comment: You better talk about device storage and removable micro sd card as external storage in Android talk is device storage.

Comment: Yes, I mean the removable micro sd card. I will edit the question accordingly.